# Laravel 7.x: Difference between fresh and refresh method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

While I was reading Laravel documentation, I faced a method named `fresh` and `refresh` on the Eloquent model. Please explain the major difference between them? I am having hard time understanding those.

Answer (score 17):

This is the comment for the `refresh` method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` :

```
/**
 * Reload the current model instance with fresh attributes from the database.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function refresh()
```

Here is the one for `fresh`:

```
/**
 * Reload a fresh model instance from the database.
 *
 * @param  array|string  $with
 * @return static|null
 */
public function fresh($with = [])
```

`refresh` will refresh the current model instance (including relationships). `fresh` will get a new instance of the model from the database and return it.